# Why does water have several different solid phase but only one liquid and gas phase

Tags: states-of-matter

Why does water have several different solid phase but only one liquid and gas phase? Is there any meaning? or any reason behind it?
Or is it just the way the nature behaves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solid phases differ by the arrangement of the molecules. Molecules in solids stay at the same place so you can have different geometrical arrangements (different phases). In liquids and gases, molecules always move, so you cannot define a fixed arrangement.

Answer (score 3):

Some other liquids can have multiple phases though. Liquid helium can undergo a phase transition between a superfluid and a non-superfluid phase.